# ArcGIS 10.2 with MatPlotLib Non-Blocking Plot

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, python-addin, matplotlib, tkinter

ArcGIS 10.2 ships with MatPlotLib 1.1.1 installed.  I am trying to display a non-blocking plot window.

Trials:

Launch an interactive plot in a Tk window from a toolbox.  This causes the plot to display and the toolbox dialog continues to run in the foreground.

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.plot(range(10), range(10))
    plt.show()
```

Changing `plt.show()` to `plt.show(block=False)` should make the plot non-blocking.  This crashes ArcMap.

Attacking this from another direction - Create a python addin-in with a single button.  That button executes the above code.  Also crashes ArcMap.

Is it possible to get a non-blocking MatPlotLib plot via arcpy?

Comment: This is an issue with Tk's event loop conflicting with ArcGIS. TK expects that it is the only GUI loop running in the process. The only real 'work-around' (and more of a band-aid in my opinion) I've seen for using Tk in ArcGIS would be to create a python script GP tool and disable running the script in process ([detailed here](http://anothergisblog.blogspot.com/2013/07/python-add-ins-and-tkinter.html))

Comment: @EvilGenius Unfortunate to hear that that is the necessary route.  Not surprising, but unfortunate.

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue with Tk's event loop conflicting with ArcGIS. TK expects that it is the only GUI loop running in the process.

The only real 'work-around' (and more of a band-aid in my opinion) I've seen for using Tk in ArcGIS would be to create a python script GP tool and disable running the script in process. This is detailed in Another GIS Blog post titled [Python Add-Ins and Tkinter](http://anothergisblog.blogspot.com/2013/07/python-add-ins-and-tkinter.html).